# WINSOCK recv call returns -1 but WSAGetLastError() is set to 0

Tags: windows, sockets, winsock

I have a piece of code that calls recv() on windows. recv() returns -1 sometimes. Calling WSAGetLastError() returns 0. This seems like very bizarre behavior. Has anyone noticed this before.

Comment: Show your code. Show the call to `recv` and the call to `WSAGetLastError`. (Either your code to call `recv` and `WSAGetLastError` is broken, you have some broken driver/filter on your Windows machine, or your socket value is wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

`WSAGetLastError()` is currently a simple alias for `GetLastError()`.  WinSock does not keep its own separate error code (though there is nothing to stop Microsoft from making that change in the future).  Like any other Win32 API function, make sure you are not making *ANY* Win32 calls between `recv()` and `WSAGetLastError()` or else you risk losing the error code.  *ALWAYS* retrieve the error code immediately after a failed function call before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem happen in a program that was calling recv() from one thread and send() on another thread with the same socket handle.  I suspect that activity on the send() thread is causing an issue with recv().

I fixed the issue by restructuring the code to perform the send() and recv() in the same thread.